# Motion tracking with good solve error but camera is skewed

Tags: camera, tracking

I need to do motion tracking of this vertical video and the solve error of the tracks is 0.45 (which is good enough for me, it doesn't need to be super accurate) however the camera has problems. The X and Y shift values of the camera are unusually high and the result is that the camera is distorted and does not track the motion correctly. I have tried manually adjusting it but with no luck. I have searched the internet and watched many tutorials but cannot fenter image description hereind a solution. With other videos I have never had this problem and I don't understand what is going wrong.
It is for my job and i need help :([image]

At this link i uploaded the .blend file and the video clip (had to use wetransfer because it doesn’t allow me to upload other file format than .blend and i'm not sure the footage is still in there)
https://we.tl/t-DRRchP2A7C

Edit: the camera in the footgae rotates around the statue

[image]

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what could be wrong, consider uploading your blend file with https://blend-exchange.com/. The first question would be : does your camera move in the footage ? If you are trying to track your footage with *Tripod* off, you should have sufficient camera movement (and thus parallax). Otherwise, the result could be bad even if  the solve error is low (I think).

Comment: @Lutzi thanks so mmuch for your answer, I added the files! In the footage the camera rotates around the statue. I tried with the tripod setting but the results are even worse. I'm new to tracking, the other scenes are not perfect but acceptable, this one just doesn't work at all..

Comment: *Tripod* is for shots where the camera doesn't translate, only rotate. If you move around the statue, my comment shouldn't apply to your case. I'll try take a look soon.